# How to execute git commands in csproj script?

Tags: git, powershell, msbuild, csproj

I have to use a git command to get the commit hash. I found several approachs but it doesn't seem to work. This is much easier if I use a powershell script where I can import git.exe with `$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"`. The fact is that I don't want to use external scripts (such as powershell ones) or importing anything. Is there a way to do that only with msbuild?

I've tried using:

```
<Exec Command="git describe --long --always" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" />
```

*error MSB3073: The command "git describe --long --always" exited with code 9009.*

and

```
<Exec Command="$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin'; git describe --long --always" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" />
```

*error MSB3073: The command "$env:Path += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin'" exited with code 123*

### EDIT

I don't know why question is on powershell :s

## UPDATE

Now I'm using the following line:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" Command="&amp; 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe' describe --long --always" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" />
```

which throws the error:
*error MSB3073: The command "& '(...)' describe --long --always" exited with code 255.*.

Comment: Have you tried with the full path to the git exe (`Command="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git describe --long --always" `?

Comment: It throws _error MSB3073: The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git describe --long --always" exited with code 9009_ (I also tried with git **.exe** full path)

Comment: Do the commands work if you run them outside of msbuild? The 9009 errorlevel means that the command/file was not found. 123 indicates that there was an unspecified error - probably parsing or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure they work. Actually for test that, I just copied the error (which prints the line I'm trying to execute) then paste it in a powershell and it works. I figured out in google that when you exec a .exe from full-path, you should use '&' at start, then the full line would be: "&amp; 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe' describe --long --always". Now it prints _exited with code 255_. I don't know what that means but I'm pretty sure it is related with the working directory (if you try to run that code outside a local repo, it throws an error).

Comment: That `git describe` command should always succeed and return something on stdout. Hence the problem is probably elsewhere. I would try and run it separately, but as close to what you have in your csproj as possible. I would also ask myself one very important question: Do I really need to do this? From what you've shown, the output isn't used - so is there any point in putting in the time and effort to get it to work?

Comment: Well, I simplified the code for the question, but yes I want to use the output.

Comment: Then I would consider using some library instead of a raw command, it's probably more reliable long term. GitVersionTask for example. https://gitversion.net/docs/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries, I did it:

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe &amp; &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe&quot; describe --long --always" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" ItemName="Version" />
</Exec>
```